# how to parse line into number and string?

Tags: c++, parsing, io, stdin

I would like to parse a sentence beginning with a number:

```
2 random sentece.
5 another one.
8 this is really long sentence.
```

Into `int number` holding the beginning number and the rest in `std::string sentence`. So in the first line, the parsing output will be `number == 2` and `sentence == "random sentence"`. The input is read from stdin, but the classical `std::cin >> number >> sentence` does'n work, since the parsing of string would end once it reaches a space. But I want to make the string beginning after the initial number to the end of line `\n`. So, how to do it in C++?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `std::getline` and `std::istringstream` as shown below. In particular in the given program, `std::getline` is used to read line by line and `std::istringstream` is used to read first the integer and then the remaining sentence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::string  sentence;
    int inputInt = 0;
    //read line by line
    while(std::cin >> inputInt && std::getline(std::cin, sentence))
    {
        std::cout<< inputInt <<"-----"<<sentence<<std::endl;
        //do the check here   
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fdmQyQDXoAUz0l2i)

Comment: The use of `std::istringstream` in this case is useful, but not really necessary: `while (std::cin >> inputInt && std::getline(std::cin, sentence)) { ... }` in the outer loop should suffice.  But, if you did use `std::istringstream`, your inner `while` should be an `if` instead, since there is only 1 set of number+substring per line.

Comment: This is a lot better than your first attempt, which didn't solve the problem at all. But it is still not ideal, since `sentence` starts immediately after the number. The example provided in the OP indicates that it should start after the whitespace.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You're right. It can be done without using `std::istringstream`. Updated the example.

Comment: @rici "*`sentence` starts immediately after the number. The example provided in the OP indicates that it should start after the whitespace*" - that is easy to fix using `std::cin >> std::ws` before calling `std::getline()`

Comment: @Remy: Sure, as long as you don't have a line with just a number. (At least, once you've removed `std::istringstream`.)

Comment: @rici that is a good point. The assumption is that no lines will have empty sentences.

Comment: @remy: when dealing with user input, you should never make assumptions about correctness.